# Any way to consolidate multiple .Trash directories

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, trash, xdg

I have a seperate data partition with a functioning .Trash directory.

But `~/.local/share/Trash` is the only directory seen by `trash:///` in nautilus.

Here's the fstab entry for the partition:

> UUID=86cf7ec3-c911-4eb9-badb-cb039f975d1d /mnt/        ext4    nodev,nosuid    02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can bind the **.Trash** directory from the data partition to `~/.local/share/Trash`.

  `mount --bind source destination`

  i.e

  `sudo mount --bind /media/sda2/.Trash ~/.local/share/Trash`